# Determine SQL Server instance being used by TFS 2015

Tags: sql-server, tfs-2015

I have a server that has TFS 2015. Originally, it was running against SQL Server 2012. I backed up the databases and then upgraded to SQL Server 2016. After upgrading to SQL Server 2016 TFS seems to work fine but I still see several entries in programs and features for SQL Server 2012.

My question: How do I check TFS 2015 to verify that it is indeed now running against SQL Server 2016?

If not, I'm guessing that if both SQL Server 2012 and 2016 are installed I have the ability to make TFS switch from one to the other?

Comment: You said you upgraded to 2016 so why would you think it's running on 2012? Most features are backwards compatible and here is a compatibility setting.

Comment: I don't know if its running SQL 2012 or SQL 2016 because they both still appear in the list of installed programs in Programs and Features. So I guess part of the question is how do I verify that I indeed upgraded SQL Server as opposed to having both versions still installed